# increment document field depending on array length

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

The reason behind that is:

Whenever somebody fetches the blog post via an api his IP adress gets added to `ips` via `$addToSet`.

In the background i have an cronjob that needs to count the array, increment the views counter and clean the array.

```
return Blog.updateMany({}, {
  $inc: {
    views: {
      $size: "$ips"
    }
  }
}).exec()
```

I try to update an field. The field `views` is numeric and `ips` is an array.

What i want to do is to increment `views` depending on the array and after that i want to clear the array.

But this fails. Has somebody an solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try [update with aggregation pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/update-documents-with-aggregation-pipeline/),

- `$size` to get total size of array in number, `$add` to sum the old and new value, and clean ips array

```
return Blog.updateMany({}, 
  [{
    $set: {
      views: { $add: ["$views", { $size: "$ips" }] },
      ips: []
    }
  }]
).exec()
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/3kNv6kCa54g)